# How to get database configurations using data source object in java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, datasource

I'm stuck in a issue related to data source objects in java. 
I have set data source connection parameters in data source object(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource). I wants to get those parameters from data source object before i call getConnection method log meaningful debug info inside catch if it catches exception.

Following is the code so far i have tried. I can get all the connection parameters from metadata as follows[ex:- connection.getMetaData().getURL()], but i wants to catch exception and log url,password,username as a log if getConnection() throws exception. Therefore, i need to get those information from data source object before it tries to creates db connection.

```
try {
        // try to get the lookup name. If error empty string will be returned
        jndiLookupName = connectionProperties.getProperty(RDBMSConstants.PROP_JNDI_LOOKUP_NAME);
        datasource = InitialContext.doLookup(jndiLookupName);

        connection = datasource.getConnection(); // WHEN THIS THROWS EXCEPTION...

        logger.info(connection.getMetaData().getURL()); // these won't work since exception already thrown.
        logger.info(connection.getMetaData().getUserName());
        logger.info(connection.getMetaData().getDriverName());
        logger.info(connection.getMetaData().getDriverVersion());

        isConnected = true; // if no errors
        logger.info("JDBC connection established with jndi config " + jndiLookupName);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        //...I WANT ALL CONNECTION PARAMETERS (URL,PASSWORD,USERNAME) HERE

        throw new SQLException("Connecting to database failed with jndi lookup", e);
    }
```

When i remote debug i get data source object as follows..

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@d47feb3{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=8; minIdle=0; initialSize=0; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=false; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/wso2_mb_1; username=a; validationQuery=null; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=30000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer;org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor;; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }
```

I can see all the url, username and password parameters are there but i can not get those. Is there a way to get these values from data source object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast to the concrete implementation of the `DataSource` - the tomcat pooled datasource provides access to `username`, `url` etc. (see [DataSource](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html) for details):

```
if (dataSource instanceof org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) {
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource tcDataSource = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource)dataSource;
    logger.info(tcDataSource.getUrl());
    logger.info(tcDataSource.getUsername());
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the DataSource implementation in Glassfish/Payara?

Comment: It's com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.DataSource40, but I don't know what maven dependency to have to use this in my project..

Comment: Maybe this one? http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.glassfish.main.jdbc.jdbc-ra.jdbc40%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jdbc40%22

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `.getPoolProperties` to get a `Properties` object

```
DataSource ds = new DataSource();
....
PoolConfiguration config = ds.getPoolProperties();
Properties dbProperties = config.getDbProperties();
```

The `dbProperties` extends the `Hashtable<Object,Object>` class so you can get an `entrySet` with all the properties

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you could do that since DataSource is just an abstraction and implemented by a driver vendor, just a connection factory. You should try to get the parameters elsewhere like a config property file or such

Comment: but that data source object contains all the db connection parameters. there should be a way to get those. 
I can't get them from elsewhere since i'm looping through lots of data source objects for different db's. I have to change the design if i have to get those config's separately.